# How to serialize object to JSON using DataAnnotation to format double property using ServiceStack request

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-text

Using `ServiceStack` I need to format this request in order that the `CodValue` property stays in this format `#.#`

```
[DataContract(Name = "request1")]
public class Request1
{
   [DataMember(Name = "codValue")]
   public double CodValue { get; set; }
}

var request1 = new Request1 { CodValue = 0.0 }
_serviceClientBase.Post(request1);
```

However, when I send the request the server side receives `CodValue = 0`
But as the server side is `Java`, it returns an error saying that it is `Java.Lang.Long` and not `Double`.

How can I force `ServiceStack` to keep the `JSON` request in the format `0.0` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a `JsConfig<T>.RawSerializerFn` to append any missing `.0` suffix,  e.g:

```
JsConfig<double>.IncludeDefaultValue = true;
JsConfig<double>.RawSerializeFn = d =>
{
    var str = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return str.IndexOf('.') >= 0 ? str : str + ".0";
};
```

To print the desired result:

```
var dto = new Request1 { CodValue = 0.0 };

dto.ToJson().Print(); //= {"codValue":0.0}
```

Comment: you have helped me a lot once again! Thanks I appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) ?

doubles will be automatically convert to `#.#` format and also there is Camel case property name resolver :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

...

class Request1
{
    public double CodValue { get; set; }
}

...

var request = new {Request1 = new Request1()};
var json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request,
    new JsonSerializerSettings() {ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()});
```

The json string looks like that :

```
{"request1":{"codValue":0.0}}
```

Comment: Great, your suggestion worked here. However, Mythz gave me a smooth way to do it using ServiceStack native options.

Comment: @RogerOliveira, no worries. I don'r really know the ServiceStack servie. Hope it will be helpfull for others pepople too ^^.